# What is a diference between いく and あるく?

Tags: word-choice

As I understand both means "walk". What is a difference here? I think that いく is more like "move" somewhere and あるく means literally walk. Is that right or something else?

Comment: What's the difference between "To go" and "To walk"? https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F https://jisho.org/search/%E6%AD%A9%E3%81%8F

Answer (score 0):

YES, that make sense and you're right.
As a Japanese native speaker I think if you have already been able to go somewhere with someone then you say "あるく" due to you can walk and to go the place on the other hand you just talking or messaging someone to go somewhere then you say "いく".
So I think the difference between them is just your situation when you say to go somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You are absolutely right! 行{い}く means "to go, to move" and 歩{ある}く means "to walk".

Note that いく can also mean "how much/many" (幾), and you can say ゆく instead of いく, and it means "to go" as well.

Comment: While the additional information you provided is not "wrong" per se... it feels like it needs some context if it's going to be included, seeing as it's about stuff that the questioner wasn't asking for and seems likely to spawn more questions.